# Is there a symbol representing "Focusing on one thing at a time"?

Tags: symbolism

I am not sure I am in the right sub of stackexchange, but I couldn't find a better fitting place - if you know a more fitting sub, please tell me!

Some symbols have become universal - like the usb symbol, or the on/off switch symbols. This lead me to thinking about whether or not there is a symbol for "Focus".

In particular I am looking for a symbol that represents "Focusing on one thing at a time" Or, in a broader sense: "Focusing solely on one thing".

Thanks for your time in advance!

Edit: I don't want to brainstorm for ideas with this question; I am just curious if anyone would know whether or not something for this existed and I just don't know about it.

Comment: check this Q&A https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/614/should-we-consider-how-to-visually-represent-questions-on-topic

Comment: Do you mean as in a camera/lens focusing? Or do you mean focus in a more figurative sense, such as paying attention to one thing only? Also what is the icon going to be used for?

Comment: in the figurative sense, as paying attention to one thing only. I don't want to use it for anything tbh, I was just curious if it existed ^^

Comment: I think the closest to this symbol is an exclamation mark.

Comment: isn't an exclamation mark rather used to highlight a specific thing/sentence/symbol(e.g. "Stop!") than actually representing the symbol itself?

Comment: Or a magnifying glass...

Comment: It depends on the context, ! sign can mean 'Pay attention to something '

Comment: for example as in road sign

Comment: What about the index symbol used in typography ☞ More information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(typography)

Comment: I guess I had something abstract in mind which simoulteanously expressed high attention to the number "one" (one thing only). Maybe Im just thinking too complicated. Thank you for your answers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be of use, but you could use possibly an *emoji* to represent this or create your own. As an *emoji* could be classed as a symbol.
 1️⃣ @

I do realise this may not look so great, but like i said you can always create your own. But you havnt told anyone enough *information* like why you need it, as im not sure what you want or mean if you understand.

There are so many ideas that could link to your project. There are other ideas that could link to your project:

**Lost and Found:**

Possibly something lost and then found if you understand me

**Focus on the small Details:**

Maybe you are symbolising either look at the bigger picture or the small one, or the small details. You might be looking closer into something.

**Clever Logo design**

After all you are on a graphic design forum so this should be on this list, you could have this Incorporated into a name or a logo/slogan depending on what suites you. I think this would work as a logo but im not sure why you would use it.

> Im not sure if there is much more you could do with it or not, but why are you asking this anyway it seems like a weird question to ask. Im not disliking your question but I was just wondering why you wanted this.

this doesnt seem like much writing or much help but I hope it helped a bit as im not sure what else to write.

**explain** more so that I can understand what you mean.

Your Welcome,
*RaGe MaGiXZ*

Comment: I dont need it at all, it was just curiosity ;) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a magnifying glass is a symbol of focusing on one thing. A detective like Sherlock Holmes.

Now days is a symbol of search but based on the first meaning... "searching for clues".